# Empty ProductLicenses and ProductListings in-app purchases , after an update

Tags: windows-8, in-app-purchase, windows-runtime

After I've updated a published app, the result of CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync() is not returning the in-app purchase items anymore.

However I can see the returned object's Name, CurrentMarket, AgeRating and FormattedPrice  are populated.

But no data in ProductListings and no data in CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses.
Before the update ( on 1st release) both Dictionary objects had items.

Anybody had the same issue or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was temporary. **It solved itself**.

Obviously the store is not very stable yet.

Comment: I'm facing the exactly same issue. Name, price and all other properties are nicely populated but product listing remains empty. Even though it's empty, I can successfully execute RequestProductPurchaseAsync(prodId, receipt) method on products I KNOW exist in Dev Center.

This is really annoying! Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue, the ProductListings is empty.
I've applied a -hopefully temporary- workaround:

```
if (productListings.Count > 0)
{ //list your iap products normally
  //...
}
else
{//strange scenario we are dealing with
 //thankfully ProductLicenses is not empty

 var productLicenses = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses;
 foreach(ProductLicense pl in productLicenses.Values)
 {
    string key = pl.ProductId;
    bool isActive = pl.IsActive;
    //use the two above for your list
 }
}
```

Comment: UPDATE: the work-around may allow one to list the iap products but it still won't allow users to purchase anything (and that is what we devs want after all). It appears the issue is wide-spread  
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a44b7364-4017-4d98-ad40-dcc03dac4311/cant-find-item-in-catalog?forum=wpdevelop&prof=required